How can I assign incrementing row numbers, except repeat the row number when two column values match the previous row?
I need to assign a row number to a large dataset that has a unique ID but could have other fields matching. I have provided example data below. The row number should increment, but repeat for rows where isLength and isThickness match is sequential order of the ID field. I have attached an image which displays what I am trying to accomplish.
DECLARE @tempData Table (ID INT Identity(1,1), isLength INT, isThickness nvarchar(6))

INSERT INTO @tempData(isLength, isThickness)
Values(126,'1.375')
    ,(122,'1.375')
    ,(120,'1.375')
    ,(120,'1.375')
    ,(120,'3')
    ,(194,'2')
    ,(242,'2')
    ,(242,'2')
    ,(122,'1.375')
    ,(122,'1.375')
    ,(108,'1.75')
    ,(60,'1.75')
    ,(108,'1.75')

SELECT ID, isLength, isThickness
FROM @tempData t
Order BY ID

Desired outcome:



ID
isLength
isThickness
Desired Row Number




1
126
1.375
1


2
122
1.375
2


3
120
1.375
3


4
120
1.375
3


5
120
3
4


6
194
2
5


7
242
2
6


8
242
2
6


9
122
1.375
7


10
122
1.375
7


11
108
1.75
8


12
60
1.75
9


13
108
1.75
10



I have tried using Rank, Dense_Rank along with Partitioning and Order By..  I'm thinking it maybe a multiple step process to achieve this, but I'm running out of ideas.

Can there be more than 2 same?

"I have tried using Rank, Dense_Rank along with Partitioning and Order By.." So where is this query???

This is called gaps and islands, the extra wrinkle is that it's two fields.
A potential solution:
select  SUM(counter) OVER(ORDER BY ID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS CalculatedID
,   *
from (
    select  case 
            when lag(isLength) over(order by ID) = islength 
            and lag(isThickness) over(order by ID) = isThickness then 0 else 1
        end AS counter
    ,   *
    from (
        VALUES  (1, 126, 1.375, 1)
        ,   (2, 122, 1.375, 2)
        ,   (3, 120, 1.375, 3)
        ,   (4, 120, 1.375, 3)
        ,   (5, 120, 3, 4)
        ,   (6, 194, 2, 5)
        ,   (7, 242, 2, 6)
        ,   (8, 242, 2, 6)
        ,   (9, 122, 1.375, 7)
        ,   (10, 122, 1.375, 7)
        ,   (11, 108, 1.75, 8)
        ,   (12, 60, 1.75, 9)
        ,   (13, 108, 1.75, 10)
    ) t (ID,isLength,isThickness,[Desired Row Number])
    ) x

The way I usually go about is:

Create a counter by compare previous values to current and set 0 if they match, otherwise 1
Summarize the counter to get the new group

Output:



CalculatedID
counter
ID
isLength
isThickness
Desired Row Number




1
1
1
126
1.375
1


2
1
2
122
1.375
2


3
1
3
120
1.375
3


3
0
4
120
1.375
3


4
1
5
120
3
4


5
1
6
194
2
5


6
1
7
242
2
6


6
0
8
242
2
6


7
1
9
122
1.375
7


7
0
10
122
1.375
7


8
1
11
108
1.75
8


9
1
12
60
1.75
9


10
1
13
108
1.75
10




Another approach if you don't want to use lag:

Find all the row that equal the previos row

Count all the "equal row"

Subtract the ID (or ROWNUMBER()) to the Count above
   WITH ex as (
      SELECT a1.*, 
            CASE WHEN a2.isLength = a1.isLength and a2.isThickness = a1.isThickness 
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END EqualRow
      FROM @tempData a1
      LEFT JOIN @tempData a2 on a2.id = a1.id - 1
   )
   SELECT *, ID - (SELECT SUM(EqualRow) FROM ex c2 WHERE c2.ID <= c1.ID) NEWROWNUMBER
   FROM ex c1



